# Are baby cougars and cheetahs properly kittens or cubs?

Tags: word-choice

I always thought felid cubs should be baby panthers (of genus *Panther*, hence "lion/tiger/jaguar/(snow) leopard cubs"). Young of other felids should be kittens (hence "lynx/bobcat kittens" for example). But it seems like baby cougars and cheetahs are a special case, probably due to their large size compared to other felids, because Google searches on nationalgeographic.com returns comparable results for "cougar/puma/cheetah kittens" and "cougar/puma/cheetah cubs".

So are baby cougars and cheetahs properly kittens or cubs?

Answer (score 1):

The Century Dictionary & Cyclopedia says:

(n) cub The young of certain quadrupeds, especially of the bear, fox, and wolf, also of the lion and tiger (more commonly whelp), and rarely of the dog and some others; a puppy; a whelp.

That is, the cub from the Irish 'cuib.' Here then a cub is a very general term for young, whilst a kitten is specifically of the Felidae. There may be an arbitrary redefinition of the words along 'scientific' lines, but I'd propose that it just feels weird to call a very obviously dangerous animal a kitten. References(such as reference.com) don't seem to imply that there is a correct term.

If we were to go with the fact that both cheetah and cougar are of Felinae, then that would reaffirm the choice of Kitten. Whilst the historical and present use of cub to describe young of any of the Carnivora would imply it would also be acceptable, but more broadly. Much as a lion is a cat ;-)

Comment: As far as I know the Scottish wild cat is the only wild felid whose young are called 'kittens'. The term may possibly be used for other, lesser-known small wild cats.

Comment: I've never heard tell of a mountain lion kitten. Have you? That would be like calling baby foxes puppies.

Comment: Weird doesn't make wrong, though as far as usage & convention goes we might say, as Kate alludes, that wild cat young are normally termed cubs, though the very existence of this question challenges that. Take this opportunity to point out that there are non-feline young referred to as kits. Certainly 'wild' is not a requirement for a young felidae to be termed cub, at any rate.

Comment: @tchrist https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/2018/08/cougar-puma-mountain-lion-kittens-mothers-video-animals/ In fact, even baby leopards are called kittens in some articles.